# Disable ( remove ) lock screen programmatically

Tags: android

can anyone tell me how to disable android lock screen?
I've tried this :

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
```

but doesn't work.

any other solution ?
thank you